# How can i fix React admin reference input problem?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

When I use a reference input and select several values, I see the error
"Associated reference no longer appears to be available". I know that this error has occurred to people when they used another parameter instead of id for rendering, but I use the default id
I hope for your help, thank you

```
<ReferenceInput
      label="Languages"
      source="languagesIds"
      reference="languages"
      resource={resource}
      perPage={INPUT_ITEMS_PER_PAGE}
    >
      <AutocompleteArrayInput
        optionText="name"
        resource={resource}
        inputType={type}
        helperText="The language of the movie's audio track. You can select multiple languages from the list."
      />
    </ReferenceInput>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjlPd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a `AutocompleteArrayInput` inside a `ReferenceInput`.
Try using a `AutocompleteArrayInput` inside a `ReferenceArrayInput`.